# Android- Augmented Reality Image to Link

Tags: android, image, frameworks, augmented-reality

Is there a framework or a code tutorial that shows how one can use the camera on your phone to recognize a predetermined image and send the user to a specified link. This should be augmented reality, but all the guides I've looked at use geolocations, and I don't want or need any of that. All I want is basically a way to recognize an image (sort of like the facial recognition of webcams). I need to design an app like this for a project, and although their might already be apps like this out, I need a guide or some framework so I can self design it. I've tried Junaio (guide didn't help me to understand all the server stuff), vuforia (cygwin didn't work, and unity needs a license), and most of the other frameworks are geolocations.

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial, it seems like a great start point:

[Android Augmented Reality](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android_augmented-reality/)

Also try these out:  on Android.

[Part 1](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK%3a-Part-1)

[Part 2](http://imrannazar.com/Augmented-Reality-with-the-Android-NDK%3a-Part-2)

Those are a 2 part article written by Imran Nazar on Augmented reality

Comment: I've already read it, there is no guide or code help, just an overview

Comment: Those seem like they have a good amount of code built into the article, along with full source code of his project. Although it may not provide the exact answers you want for your project, it will be able to push you onto the right path. Remember, Augmented Reality is still being researched. Google and SO will be your best friends on the road ahead.

Comment: Yea, been trying this for a couple of days and used Google and SO heavily. You are the first one to provide me with something manageable, thank you.

Comment: Hey Addison, have you tried using the code before? I tried using it and I keep getting an java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on my device. Just emailed the guide maker, but was also wondering if you had tried before. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't actually run the code, no. But to help you out, check the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375810/exception-in-initializer-error

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking, or for other people looking this up, I've used this [tutorial](http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/hello-world/). It walks you through everything from the andorid environment setup through to different content types and tracking configurations. It also has example codes, and assets to test the augmentations. Pretty comprehensive. Hope this helps.