# Do java applets have to be signed with trusted cert authority with new v7 update 21?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, runtime-error

I would require some help with fixing my problem.

As posted in one of my previous questions i have a problem with java applet.
[Java viewer not working after JRE 1.7.0.21 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142889/java-viewer-not-working-after-jre-1-7-0-21-update)

I tried several things, but was unable to make the app work.
I would try to obtain trusted cert, but spending 300$ without being sure is not acceptable.

I would kindly ask if someone is willing to help me out to fix this problem...

With kind regards, no9.

Comment: I saw recently that Comodo goes 'as low as' $180 per year, if you consider that low (I don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 7 update 21 it depends on the Java security settings of the Java Control panel if self-signed certificates are accepted for Java applets. If the Slider of the Java Control Panel is set to the highest security setting, then only trusted cert authorities will be accepted.

In a future version (October 2013) Oracle will probably remove this slider and make the highest security setting the only remaining selection. (Source: JAX2013 talk "Moving the Java Platform forward" of Wolfgang Weigend )

Comment: Do you know what the default setting is? Because that's probably the most likely setting for most users.

Comment: The current default setting is "high" - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html