# Java 7 security restrictions for applets

Tags: java, security, applet, java-7

I've implemented an applet and so far has been working with no hassle with Java 6. Recently, when I switched to Java 7 the applet stopped working, showing the following exception in javascript console:

`Uncaught Error: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "user.home" "read")`

This behavior is consistently reproductible, just switching from one Java version to the other with the Linux command `update-java-alternatives`.

The applet is self-signed and all its public methods invoke `AccessController.doPrivileged()`, for example:

```
public File chooseFile() {
    return AccessController.doPrivileged( new PrivilegedAction<File>() {
        public File run() {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);                
            return chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ? 
                    chooser.getSelectedFile() : null;
        }
    } );
}
```

I've solved the problem using a `java.policy` local file, but requiring special installation procedures is not an option.

Does anybody know which are those Java 7 new security restrictions and/or how to circumvent them?

Answer (score 1):

Some information can be found in [Do java applets have to be signed with trusted cert authority with new v7 update 21?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663426/do-java-applets-have-to-be-signed-with-trusted-cert-authority-with-new-v7-update/16664342#16664342) and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html

There will be more restrictions in the next scheduled security update in October 2013.

One requirement will be to switch from a selfsigned applet to a certificate from a trusted authority.

Comment: Thanks for the links, they are being quite enlightening. I have created a certificate and imported to my local keystore, but I guess that as long as I don't use a real CA it will be treated as self-signed. Nevertheless, I've set the Java console slider to the minimum security level and I'm getting the same results. It makes little sense for me :(

Comment: there have been some updates again in the latest release Java 7u40 (see the release notes of this release)

Comment: Java 7u51 has added more restrictions again for Applets and Webstart