# Class not loaded - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, android-studio, global-variables, android-gradle-plugin

I have imported a working project from eclipse into Android Studio and when I try to run in in android studio app crashesh after some debugging I found the reason.

I have a public class called Global where I store all data that I constantly need through all my activities.

And the crash is at:

```
Global.veriable = value;
```

At the start of onCreate on my MainActivity. I tryed by importing Global class as well but the result was the same. In debugging found this:

Class not loaded.

And the exception:

```
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at si.comtron.tronpos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at si.comtron.tronpos.content.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:122)
            at si.comtron.tronpos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<clinit>(BouncyCastleProvider.java:51)
            at si.comtron.tronpos.content.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:122)
            at si.comtron.tronpos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.spongycastle.util.Strings
            at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.config.ProviderConfigurationPermission.calculateMask(ProviderConfigurationPermission.java:64)
            at org.spongycastle.jcajce.provider.config.ProviderConfigurationPermission.<init>(ProviderConfigurationPermission.java:58)
            at org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProviderConfiguration.<clinit>(BouncyCastleProviderConfiguration.java:16)
            at org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<clinit>(BouncyCastleProvider.java:51)
            at si.comtron.tronpos.content.Global.<clinit>(Global.java:122)
            at si.comtron.tronpos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:172)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [exception in initializer error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375810/exception-in-initializer-error)

Comment: True, didnt check it since it was not android

Comment: `Retrofit` have recently updated to 2.7.1 version. After that Android 4.x clients have crashed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60071876/2914140.