# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects[]

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects[]，but i don't know how to solve it,please help me!!!!

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects[]
at com.yingshibao.gsee.fragments.DuoBeiClassFragment1.newInstance(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      onCreateLoader(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      onLoadFinished(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      getDownloadClassRoom(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      onLoaderReset(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      onLoadFinished(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      lambda$initSchedule$179(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      access$000(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
                                                      access$200(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
at com.yingshibao.gsee.fragments.DuoBeiClassFragment1$$Lambda$1.onClick(DuoBeiClassFragment1.java)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17729)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5166)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:768)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Please take a look a this post asked before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778644/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-util-objects

Comment: @EAKTEAM thank you

Comment: Can i post it as a solution , and mark it as answer if you find helpfull ?

Comment: I use Objects in AysncTask, i fix it,but i don't know whether useful or not

Comment: @EAKTEAME what should i do? i don't know how to mark it

Comment: i have posted my answer ... check the answer to mark as helped if it help you

Comment: thanks...for you attention

Comment: You're welcome,my reputation less than 15,so i can't vote,sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this post maybe it will help you ....

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778644/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-util-objects)

The exception is thrown because all static methods of java.util.Objects are available above API 19 (Android 4.4.+).

in API 10 (Android 2.3.+) that method doesn't exist in that Android version and NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

If you want to check api level programmatically you can do:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
// your code available only above api 19
} else {
// compatibility code
}
```