# Eclipse Mars for PHP Developer Error

Tags: eclipse

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Error Reporting System".
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Why does this happen?

Comment: please provide some code. And have a look here, maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375810/exception-in-initializer-error

Answer (score 0):

I have update my jre and now it works!