# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError with Google Maps Direction Routing

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am getting an exception with my app that uses google maps direction routing app, programmed in Android Studio.
I also added all needed API keys from google.

Thank you :)

```
03-30 21:46:37.216 20364-20364/com.directions.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

at com.directions.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)                                                                               
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)                                                                               
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)                                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)                                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)                                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)                                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)                                                                               
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                               
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)                                                                               
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)                                                                               
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                               
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)                                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)                                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)                                                                               
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api$ClientKey

at com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places.<clinit>(Unknown Source)                                                                               
at com.directions.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)                                                                                
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)                                                                                
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2210)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:142)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)                                                                                
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)                                                                                
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)                                                                                
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)                                                                               
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)                                                                                
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: In particular, line 81 of MainActivity.java. `com.directions.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)`

Comment: You get an ExceptionInInitializerError if something goes wrong in the static initializer block. Check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375810/exception-in-initializer-error

Comment: Have you solved this?