# Selenium NoSuchSession on linux

Tags: java, linux, selenium

i tried to run selenium tests created on windows machine. I change driver to linux version. Added it to PATH. But every time i got

```
org.selenium.NoSUchSessionException
```

i use latest browser with latest driver

I define driver it like that :

```
public class AuthTestSteps {
private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;
@Given("^blah_blah$")
public void method() throws MalformedURLException{

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
}
```

***Solution:***

im my case solution was adding driver manager and options to chrome like "--no-sandbox", because it was run from root user.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 1):

While executing *Selenium Tests* you need to pass the absolute path of the *WebDriver* binary first through `System.setProperty()` line then initialize the *Web Browser* as follows :

```
public class AuthTestSteps 
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Given("^blah_blah$")
    public void method() throws MalformedURLException
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/path/to/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path of chrome driver. change your code like this.

```
public class AuthTestSteps {
private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;
@Given("^blah_blah$")
public void method() throws MalformedURLException{

    // assuming that your chrome driver is located inside
    // your project(src/main/resources/browser_driver/chromedriver)
    // take absolute path for chrome driver
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/browser_driver/chromedriver");
    String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", absolutePath);
}
```

Comment: Nope, i was tryed this way, but it doesn't help. Still same error